# How to translate the motto: "Together we lead the way enabling Dreams and everyday aspirations for a greater good"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, motto

A company has this long internal motto in the English language, but I was thinking it could be shortened a lot in Latin and maybe sound smarter, and be more easy to remember.

This is how it is depicted graphically:

> **Together We Lead The Way** 
>  
>  *enabling* 
>  **Dreams And Everyday
>   Aspirations** 
>  
> *for* 
>  
>  **A Greater Good**

Answer (score 6):

"Greater good" is actually (at least) from Aristotle, μεῖζον ἀγαθὸν, which in Latin should translate as "majus bonum" (in your scenario, perhaps better spelt as "maius bonum" to avoid pronunciation misunderstanding). 
"For the greater good" would translate "ad maius bonum". 
If I would have to choose a Latin motto for a company, I would limit myself to that, as it does convey the main message.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest an elegiac couplet:

> *Ad studium, desiderium cuiusque diei
>
>     tendimus nos una, crescat ut haec bonitas.*
>
> Together we strive for desires and aspirations of each day, so that this goodness may grow.

I'm not sure if this would work for you.
Any comments or suggestions are welcome.
I can try to write a new version if I know which direction to take this to.

Comment: Just for inspiration to the last part about: A Greater Good.
I came across and old speech by pope BENEDICT, where he uses the phrase:

"in a search for the true good of mankind and of society."

and the Latin version:

"dum verum quaeritur hominis ac societatis bonum."


Link to document: https://w2.vatican.va/content/benedict-xvi/en/messages/urbi/documents/hf_ben-xvi_mes_20050420_missa-pro-ecclesia.html

Link to a short audio discussion of this part with Reginald Foster:
http://frcoulter.com/latin/latinlover/latin_07_11_07.mp3

Answer (score 3):

Personally I'd opt for *summum bonum*. From Wikipedia:

> Summum bonum is a Latin expression meaning "the highest good", which was introduced by the Roman philosopher Cicero, to correspond to the Idea of the Good in ancient Greek philosophy. The *summum bonum* is generally thought of as being an end in itself, and at the same time containing all other goods.